# Trying to decrypt the output from a BLE scale

Tags: decryption

I'm trying to decrypt the readings from a BLE scale, which seems to be transmitting readings in the manufacturer data.

Here are a few readings using python bleak library to scan device advertisements:

#no weight on scale:

b'\x0f\x05\x02\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x02\x00P\xfb\x19\x87\xd1Q\xf5'

#scale reads "19.90g":

b'\x0f\x05\x02\x00\x07\xc6Z\x00\x02\x00P\xfb\x19\x87\xd1Q4'

#scale reads "53.92g":

b'\x0f\x05\x02\x00\x15\x10Z\x00\x02\x00P\xfb\x19\x87\xd1Q\xf0'

#scale reads "21.18g":

b'\x0f\x05\x02\x00\x08FZ\x00\x02\x00P\xfb\x19\x87\xd1Q\xbb'

Comment: The first byte 0x0f must be the message bytes number. The last one is certainly a checksum. And for example in the second message 0x07c6 = 1990 in decimal.